# Revert to default Apache, PHP, MySQL Settings on Snow Leopard

Tags: php, mysql, apache, osx-snow-leopard

I've learned the hard way that there are various ways to setup apache, php and mysql on Snow Leopard, and that I am not familiar enough with server config, php, or mysql to follow just any method.

I would really like to start fresh. Yeah, I know, I should've done the setup while saving default backup files for EVERYTHING, but unfortunately i guess I did not cover all of my tracks and I'm not sure how to completely revert to original settings, safely.

Any suggestions? Any resources? There are a ton of tutorials for setup, but I'm not seeing any for reverting back to default.

Much Appreciated :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to set up your mac is using Homebrew.  You first need to open up the App Store and download latest XCode (4.3.3 I believe) and it takes a while.  You'll then need to go into Settings and install Command Line Tools for XCode.  After you do this, it includes the necessary GCC compilers, etc.

Then the "magic" happens.  You open the Terminal app on your Mac and follow these instructions:

**Install Homebrew:**

- https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Installation

**Install MySQL:**

- brew install mysql   (yep, that's it)

**Install PHP:**

- brew install php     (yep, that's it)

---

Here are a couple tutorials (I use nginx -> php-fastcgi or php-fpm instead):

- http://www.davidxia.com/2012/05/turn-mac-os-x-lion-into-a-lamp-web-server-without-mamp
- http://justinhileman.info/article/building-a-lamp-development-environment-on-snow-leopard/

Comment: Thanks @mikes. I'll look into your recommendations for setting up a fresh apache, php, mysql environment on Snow Leopard. But first, any suggestions on the safest process for me to revert back to the default apache and php settings, and remove my current mysql installation? This way, I hope to start over and install mysql, and set php and apache appropriately.

Comment: Apologies for missing that part. Unfortunately no easy answers there but homebrew typically finds installed packages and resolves or notifies of conflicts.  You might have extra "stuff" lingering but as long as it doesn't interfere with operating, it's just using up a little cheap disk space.

You want to check the plist files in Startup Items to ensure they are not trying to run old versions, then delete any references of old files.

SEE: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/41143/how-to-revert-default-mac-apache-install-to-original

Answer (score 1):

I would go for a linux virtual machine as webserver. That's my setup on my MacOS, I use virtualbox with an Ubuntu OS.

The main advantage I see are:

- Easy backup / restore / maintenance
- The MacOS stays clean
- On Linux you can try a "real" production-like env, installing whatever you need

Comment: another quick response, thank you @napolux. This is an interesting suggestion that I had not thought of. I'll look into this too. I have virtualbox with ubuntu, but only for previewing my site designs on it per a request from the head of tech at my company. Would you still suggest this option if I mentioned that I work more with web design coding (html5, css3, jquery...) and not as much with programming/development coding (javascript, php, mysql...)? I'm learning the basics of programming, but I'm only just starting to learn php/mysql.

Comment: Your VM will be just a webserver. Your main development, design, whatever will still be on the mac. I use to share a folder between my mac and the VM, mapping the shared folder as the root folder of the apache for the virtual machine.